# Proof that countable compliment topology is a topology

Tags: general-topology

I have the definition of countable compliment topology as :

X is any non-empty set and τ = τc is the
collection of all subsets U such that $U^{c}$ = X\U is either countable or all of X.

How do I prove that the countable complement topology is a topology?

Comment: A topology must have three properties. Which of them has you stuck?

Comment: I dont know how to go about showing them. Where do I start?

Comment: Depends on what is meant by "countable." Some people include finite in that term, some people do not. If you don't include finite in that term, it is not true.

Comment: You must prove that 1) $\varnothing$ and $X$ are elements of $\tau$. 2) If $U,V\in\tau$ then $U\cap V\in\tau$ and 3) If $U_i\in\tau$ for $i\in I$ then the union of the $U_i$ is an element of $\tau$. Start wherever you like.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but in this context finite sets are - I would say definitely - labeled as countable sets.

Comment: @drhab Oh, it is obvious to you and me, but to the OP working on the problem, it might not be.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, then from now on it will be obvious to the OP as well, I think.